# Custom fields issue

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I installed the plugin Advanced Custom Fields and created few custom fields , but I'm not able to add any content in it. How is this done?

Comment: ACF has extensive documentation, check the official site and you'll be able to get it working.

Comment: @Shahil, I didn't noticed this was a closed Question when I approved/improved your edit. There's no point in editing them (or there is? some mod opinion?). Try to focus on active/open content. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within Admin under 'Screen Options' tab, make sure 'Custom Fields' is ticked.

Then below your Post you should find your Custom Fields area.

From here, select the custom field from the dropdown and add content in the value field on the right.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The OP doesn't mention in title or content, but the Question is tagged with [tag:advanced-custom-fields]

Comment: Spotted that myself, but zero mention in title/content like you say.